# Establish a band or Found a band or else?

Tags: verbs, translation

The example sentece: "The Beatles was established/founded/else in 1970s by their members"
What is the correct verb?

Comment: [Formed.](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=qryAwfpHG8o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Established is more appropriate for cases involving an actual establishment (say, a company, an organization).

Founded is a good choice of word to use here.

I would also say that ****formed**** is a good choice for this occasion.

> The band Tool was formed in the 90s by an amazing bunch.

Comment: +1 Try to include something in support, too, like comparing definitions and usage.